# text.slice is not a function - How to slice some text from a ReactMardown component?

Tags: javascript, slice

I'm implementing a read more read less button in a nextjs app with strapi backend.
I try to use a .slice but the text comes from the API through a ReactMarkdown component.

So I get this error :

```
TypeError : text.slice is not a function
```

I started with this before I got stopped by the error

const ReadMore = ({ children, maxCharacterCount = 100 }) => {
const text = children;

const resultString = text.slice(0, 100);

return (

{resultString}

Read more
{/* {isTruncated ? "Voir plus" : "Voir moins"} */}

);

```
 <ReadMore>
       <ReactMarkdown source={item.texte} />
  </ReadMore>
```

Comment: Try turning the text to an array by first calling the `.split()` method on it before slice it. `text.split()` then `text.slice(0, 100)`.

Comment: What does `text` actually contain? If it's a string, `slice(0,100)` should work just fine. Based on it originally being named `children`  I'm guessing you're trying to use it on a DOM array or something like that

Comment: Actually text contain <p> et <h> titles, not just one string

Comment: OK, yeah, if you want to use string methods, you need to make sure you're working with a string first.  (And if your string contains HTML tags you definitely don't want to be arbitrarily truncating it, because you'll wind up chopping off the middle of a tag, or keeping a `<p>` and dropping its `</p>` -- instead you'll need to walk into that tree and truncate the text-only parts.)

Comment: Ah yes. I did not think about it. So it's not possible to do this with rich marckdown text from my back office but only by using simple text areas?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "rich markdown text", markdown is just a string too.  ReactMarkdown converts that string into DOM nodes, which should probably happen _after_ you truncate the text, not before.  (This would be much easier to answer if you would just tell us specifically what the `text` variable contains!)

Comment: I use Strapi and ReactMardown. The markdown is converted in HTML and full of different tags like h1, h2, p ... So that's why I can slice I guess.